# sleep until condition is true in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any better way in Ruby to sleep until some condition is true ?

```
loop do 
  sleep(1)
  if ready_to_go
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: usually, that's the common way to do it. or you can use task scheduler such as cron etc.

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? Are you worried about it being the equivalent of constantly asking "Are we there yet?", or are you worried about it being verbose?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`until` can be a statement modifier, leading to:

```
sleep(1) until ready_to_go
```

You'll have to use that in a thread with another thread changing `ready_to_go` otherwise you'll hang.

```
while (!ready_to_go)
  sleep(1)
end
```

is similar to that but, again, you'd need something to toggle `ready_to_go` or you'd hang.

You could use:

```
until (ready_to_go)
  sleep(1)
end
```

but I've never been comfortable using `until` like that. Actually I almost never use it, preferring the equivalent `(!ready_to_go)`.

Comment: You just gotta watch out for conditions that can never result in a true statement or you'll end up in a black-hole. I learned that lesson when I was writing assembly language and C, and locked up my machine so bad I had to pull the power cord to get it to return to my control. Several times. Sigh. :-)

Comment: Did you mean `unless` or `until`? (They're both negatives, and they both begin with "un")

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `waitutil` gem as described at http://rubytools.github.io/waitutil/, e.g.

```
require 'waitutil'

WaitUtil.wait_for_condition("my_event to happen", 
                            :timeout_sec => 30,
                            :delay_sec => 0.5) do
  check_if_my_event_happened
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sleep_until(time)
  time.times do
    break if block_given? && yield
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
sleep_until(18){till_i_die}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this form since it is simple and only uses sleep if needed after it tests for the done condition:

```
begin
  ready_to_go = do_some_action
end until ready_to_go or not sleep 1
```