# Is it possible to change what a thread is doing in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, macos

Say I create a thread like this:

```
thread = Thread.new do
 loop do
  puts "tick"
  sleep(1)
 end
end
```

What if somewhere down the line I want this thread to stop doing that and execute some_method(), how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have the other thread set a variable, and this thread check its value. The approach is elaborated in this answer: [sleep until condition is true in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975747/sleep-until-condition-is-true-in-ruby)

If `puts "tick"` isn't necessary you could use a condition variable instead.